# Which email client is fast enough for a Maildir containing one million emails?

Tags: software-recommendation, email

I have a Maildir, which subfolders contain about one million emails. Mutt is so slow on it. Any better choice?

PS: An email deduplicate tool contained is better. Normal scripts keep the index in memory which end up being killed.

Comment: @eric-yorba sorry i didn't noticed ...i have deleted my answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such number of mails [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org) is an obvious choice. You can try using [alot](https://github.com/pazz/alot) as a frontend.

Answer (score -1):

I reccomend Thunderbird.

Search for it in the Dash. It's pre-installed.

Log in to your server.

And there you go! Your e-mails!

Hope this helps!!!